# How to adjust these soft close hinges on the door?

Tags: doors, kitchens, cabinets, hinges

The cabinets in my kitchen have soft close hinges --- see pictures below. The hinges brand is [Hettich](https://web.hettich.com/en-us/products-catalog/hinges#&documentType=undefined). One of the cabinets suddenly stopped closing "softly" and it just slams right back in.

The faulty door has 2 hinges as shown below. I suppose one of them or both got loose somehow.

How do I adjust the hing(es), so the door closes as expected again?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems they just "go bad" after a while. I'm sure that varies from brand to brand (and hinge to hinge) but I don't think it's uncommon. Did you contact Hettich?

Answer (score 0):

I can't make out the branding on your existing hinges, so can't be really specific, but sometimes the soft close spring/damper just breaks on these hinges.

The thing to do is source replacements, which isn't (unfortunately) as easy as it sounds, as there's a staggering variety in these hinges.

Best case is that you can find a real brick and mortar cabinet hardware store. Just bring yours in and they'll figure it out.

If that's not an option, you might get lucky by bringing the hinge and seeing what the box stores are selling, but there's an equal chance that you won't. (In advance, figure out what overlay the hinge is -- full/half/inset.) Google 'euro hinge types' to understand the differences.

Online, there are plenty of places; your best bet would be to engage one of them in a chat to explain exactly what you need.

The good news is that once you have new hinges, replacement is really easy.

Comment: Hi and thanks. The hinges brand is Hettich, very similar to [these ones](https://web.hettich.com/en-us/products-catalog/hinges#&documentType=undefined). I can't find for my life whether there is any closing speed adjustment or switch. Anyways, I will probably just end up buing new ones and replacing both.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

See below-linked article for "how to".

https://www.wikihow.com/Adjust-Soft-Close-Hinges

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please edit to include the highlights of how to adjust the hinge so it's still useful when the host page disappears.